# Bootstrap 3, navbar: How to break a long text in span?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I creating a navbar with a dropdown to display notification. I set the dropdown and its item with width 200px.

My problem is: I have some long text to notificate and try to break it to new line but it not work.

Do you have any idea/solution to resolve it?

My demo: [Please resize the result console to width 800px to see the problem!](https://jsfiddle.net/hit711/uqnmdec3/5/)

```
<style>
    #notify>*{
        width: 200px;
        /* white-space: normal;
        word-wrap: normal; */
    }

    #notify>li>a{
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="accountMng">
            <li class="dropdown" id="navbar-notify">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"><span class="badge badge-red">2</span></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" id="notify">
                    <li><a href="#"><span><strong>UserXXXXXXXXX</strong> responsed your product.</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Product <strong>XXXXX</strong> out of stock!</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egbRN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.dropdown-menu>li>a` has a **`white-space: nowrap;`** declaration.

Overwrite it with **`white-space: initial;`**